# Printing strings in same line

Tags: python, linux

I tried to get the output of python as

```
def main():
    i=raw_input()
    a=input()
    print(i*a)
    main()
```

input:hello,
      2.
output: "hellohello" 
but i am getting output as 
output:" hello
        hello "
.how can i get the two strings as output continuously in same line from one print statement.for example:"hellohello "

Comment: I just tested this and it works as expected in my console

Comment: try `i = i.strip()` to remove whitespace from the end of `i`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh there is no whitespace at the end of `i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the white space from the single execution of `print`. Use `.strip()` function as (as I believe you have white space within your `i` string):

```
print(i.strip()*a)
```

But if you want all the executions of `print` in single line, you should use `end` argument of `print` to define empty string. Your `print` statement should be like:

```
print(i.strip()*a, end='')
```

Comment: Thanks bro....actually the problem is I placed the main inside the function,so its not printing the output

Answer (score 0):

based on the fact that you are using `raw_input` I'm assuming you are using python 2.  Therefor you could just change the `print()` with a `print` and your code should work

```
def main():
  i=raw_input()
  a=input()
  print i*a  <---
  main()
```

Comment: i am getting output in  two lines, but i need them in a single line bro

Comment: this code does not put the output on two lines.  Are you using python 2?

Comment: i am using python <3

Comment: Thanks bro....actually the problem is I placed the main inside the function,so its not printing the output